# Disabling HTML5 element id as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740275/html-element-id-as-javascript-variable), and it seems that this "feature" of the browser to create a top-level variable for each id in the document is not recommended to use.  Furthermore, as it seems like a pretty big issue for potential conflicts (i.e. if one has dynamic id names it becomes possible they will trash an important variable in the code).  So, how can one disable this in HTML 5?  By default, it appears to be enabled (looking at it in Firebug under Firefox, for example).  From what I can tell, HTML5 doesn't have directives like "use strict" suggested (by some, and refuted by others on the above page) to turn it off.

And if it can't be turned off, is there any reason to not go ahead and use the variable name rather than calling getElementById, such as performance reasons?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "disable" it. And it should be fine to use the variable name, except I wouldn't suggest it because it isn't standard (although it *may* work in all browsers you've tested/seen in), and it's possible that it conflicts with actual JavaScript code; it's just easier to **not** use. And I wouldn't worry about performance - `document.getElementById()` is surprisingly fast, even for a DOM operation

Comment: @Ian ok. further experimentation (at least in Firefox) seems to suggest that if you create a variable with the same name as an element id, it takes precedence over the id, so there shouldn't be any conflict as long as elements are always referenced by document.getElementById().

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right. Anything you declare as a `var` shadows variables that were created by the browser based on `id`. Things can get messy/confusing later when you go to reference a variable (maybe forget to declare it with `var`) and it references an element instead of what you meant. The point is that you shouldn't rely on browsers to implement this feature (because it's not standard), when you can rely on `document.getElementById` that should be just as performant and is reliant. Stick with variable declaration and `document.getElementById`