# ajax post data error [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote this script to for a contact form on my website, everything works however instead of storing the data in me database all is get is
`[object HTMLCollection]`  c
an anyone tell me what this is? 
or what is going wrong? i have had a look on google but i cant find much information on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //when the button is clicked



    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {



        $('.small').hide();



              var name = $("input#name").val();

            if (name == "") {

          $("span#name").show();

          return false;

        }



              var name = $("input#email").val();

            if (name == "") {

          $("span#email").show();

          return false;

        }



              var name = $("input#subject").val();

            if (name == "") {

          $("span#subject").show();

          return false;

        }



             var name = $("textarea#message").val();

            if (name == "") {

          $("span#message").show();

          return false;

        }







        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;



            $.ajax({

          type: "POST",

          url: "/scripts/send_message.php",

          data: dataString,



          });

    $("#messagearea").load("console/new_message_profile.php?sent=1");

    });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: You have the same variable names as `name` for all and you are trying to pass variables that aren't initialised in ajax

Comment: please indent your code appropriate for reading.

Comment: Your code is hardly readable. Please consider proper indentation and spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Namit mentioned, you use `name` as a variable everywhere. Building your string, `email`, `subject` and `message` are uninitialised.

They should give you an `undefined` - but no, due to a weird Internet Explorer behaviour (see [Is there a spec that the id of elements should be made global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6381425/1048572)) these variables hold DOM elements. As you seem to have multiple elements with the same id (NEVER DO THAT), here a `<span>` and an `<input>`, the variables even seem to hold `HTMLCollection` objects. Which are casted to the string `[object HTMLCollection]`, when you concat them with other strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the variable `name` for all the other fields as well. You need to change the field name to the respective input id.

```
var name = $("input#email").val();    // needs to be email 
var name = $("input#subject").val();  // needs to be subject
```