# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Java Scripts

Tags: javascript

```
function correlativo(sucursal){

    var tipo=document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    var correlativo= document.getElementById('correlativo')


    var ajax=nuevoAjax(); 
    ajax.open("POST", "../ajax/correlativo_ajax.php", true); 
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    ajax.send("tipo="+tipo+"&sucursal="+sucursal); 

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
        if (ajax.readyState==4) 
        { 
            var respuesta=ajax.responseXML; 
            correlativo.innerHTML=respuesta.getElementsByTagName("correlativo")[0].childNodes[0].data; 



        } 
    }
}
function guardarOt(){

    //
    var sucursal_ciudad = document.getElementById('sucursal_ciudad').value;

    correlativo(sucursal_ciudad); //This line i get the ERROR
}
```

I have this error :C, i dont know why.
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
When I call this function correlativo(); i get this error i dont know why ;( , please helpme i  need a lot the solution

Comment: What does `nuevoAjax()` return?

Comment: In which line do you get the error? It seems either `nuevoAjax` or `correlativo` are not available.

Comment: Do you know what the line number is? If so, tell us what code is on that line?

Comment: i get the error in correlativo(sucursal_ciudad);
And function correlativo(sucursal) is in the 1162 line,
and function guardarOt() in 1185

Comment: You should not be naming both your variable and function `correlativo`. This is causing a shadow and potentially causing the exception you are seeing. Also, some browsers will create global variables for DOM elements, which would effectively destroy your `correlativo` function.

Comment: @jbabey , thanks man :D! you giveme the anwser

Comment: @HectorChaconPerez I've posted it as an answer. If it helped solve your problem, you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely happening due to a [browser "feature"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/should-the-id-of-elements-be-made-global-variables-and) which creates global variables corresponding to each element on your page, with the element's ID as the variable name.

If you have an element on your page with the ID `correlativo` (which you probably do since you're performing `getElementById('correlativo')`) this would effectively overwrite your declaration of `function correlativo ...`, causing it to not exist when you try to execute it from `guardarOt`.

TLDR: Change the name of your `correlativo` function to something else and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function and a variable with the name `correlativo`. Change one of those.

Also you have `nuevoAjax` which is not defined in the code provided. Make sure that this is a function. Not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing nuevoAjax.

```
function nuevoAjax(){
    var xmlhttp=false;
    try {
        mlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
        }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
};
```