# How Do I Assign a input to a variable?

Tags: java, variables, input, var

**When I try running this code, it says: index.html?descricao=:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set
property 'value' of null
at index.html?descricao=:14**

```
java code: var inputValue = document.getElementById("reply").value;

html: <textarea id="reply" name="reply" onKeyPress="enterpressalert(event, this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: please add more details

Comment: Yeah there's no context here.  Show us the entire class where that assignment takes place.  Also please describe what frameworks and libraries you are using because `Uncaught TypeError` is not a standard exception.

Comment: Are you sure this is Java?  Or JavaScript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510071/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-java-scripts