# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form method="post" id="login">

Username: <input type="text" value="" name="usr" />
Password: <input type="password" value="" name="pw"/>
<input type="submit" id="log" name="log" value="Login" style="width:250px;"/><br/>

</form>
```

But i keep getting cannot read property for my javascript with this line:

```
var usr = login.usr.value;
var pw = login.pw.value;
```

What is the reason i get this error ?

Comment: I hope you have `var login = document.getElementById('login')` in there somewhere...

Comment: Kolink - there are no IDs defined, so that will not work.

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to load?

Comment: windows.onload is used yes :)

Comment: @Kolink it's an old [though terrible] JavaScript convention that an HTML form with a name attribute will be available as a global variable with that name, and inputs with names inside that form will be accessible as named properties of that variable. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6381766/59461).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give your form a name and change your code like below :

```
<form method="post" id="login" name="login">

Username: <input type="text" value="" name="usr" />
Password: <input type="password" value="" name="pw"/>
<input type="submit" id="log" name="log" value="Login" style="width:250px;"/><br/>

</form>
```

and the in your javascript :

```
var usr = document.login.usr.value;
```

You can check [here (jsfiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/QsXK7/).

Comment: Ah thats the ticket. Form name rather than id!

Comment: There are many ways to do it, since you used name I implemented it using the name but you can do it with id as well using `document.getElementById()`

Comment: However form name will not validate in some cases

Comment: It is not valid xhtml strict for example

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" value="" name="usr" />` does not magically become the variable `login.usr`, you need to define the value based on the DOM.

```
var usr = document.login.usr.value;
```

Comment: ok that fixed the initial problem but that gives `Cannot read property 'usr' of undefined `

Comment: In Firefox, Chrome, and IE it seems to do so: http://jsfiddle.net/dAE6X/, since the DOM element with the id of `login` gets a JS variable of the same name, and form elements are added as subproperties of the form element according to their `name`. (I know it's horribly gross, but that doesn't mean it's causing the OP's problem.) ...Or did I make a mistake in my own fiddle code, somehow?

Comment: This does not work with a form with an ID only in several browsers

Comment: For scripting, I prefer to use IDs, mainly because I use jQuery, and getting a value by ID in jQuery is very short.

Comment: Actually it *does* magically become the variable `login.usr` in a lot of browsers, unfortunately. (If the form is named "login", that is.) [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/WYu3r/) works in Chrome, IE and Firefox, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementsByName`:

The `getElementsByName()` method accesses all elements with the specified name.

```
var usr = document.getElementsByName('usr')[0].value;
var pw = document.getElementsByName('pw')[0].value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3RvL/

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
<form method="post" id="login">
  Username: <input type="text" value="" name="usr" />

var form = document.getElementById("login"); //DOM access
var usr = form.elements["usr"]; // Forms access
```

Method 2 - not valid xhtml:

```
<form method="post" name="login">
  Username: <input type="text" value="" name="usr" />

var form = document.login; // Forms access
var usr = form.elements["usr"]; // Forms access
```

Method 3:

```
<form method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" value="" name="usr" />

var usr = document.getElementsByName("usr")[0]; // first field on page named this
```

Method 4: - preferred these days since ID MUST be unique - less useful if there are more forms with usr on the page that needs same validation

```
<form method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" value="" id="usr" name="usr" />

var usr = document.getElementById("usr");
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in every browser:

```
   document.forms["login"].elements["usr"].value;
   document.forms["login"].elements["pw"].value;
```