# Can I access DOM element directly by id?

Tags: javascript, dom

In javascript I always use docuemtn.getElementById to access DOM elements, but recently I accidentally accessed it using id only and it worked. Example:

```
<input id="element_id" type="text">
```

and in javascript

```
element_id.onclick=fun;
```

Is it correct code? Why does it work? (in all browsers I have)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in some browsers, the elements are available as global variables named for their ID.

Don't use this "feature". It's non-standard, and not universally supported.

Comment: What is this 'feature' called?  Can we look up support for it on CanIUse.com, or somewhere similar?

Comment: oh, found it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

Answer (score 0):

It will work in some browsers some of the time. For example, if you create the following element:

```
<div id="Math">I'm a math div!</div>
```

both `Math` and `window.Math` will return `MathConstructor {}`, since that's what the normal `window.Math` returns. (Tested in Chrome [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hq4GB/2/))