# Accessing a Jquery selector as an object property, unexpected outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have a `div` that looks like:

```
<div id="testDiv">some stuff in here</div>
```

and I have a script that defines an object literal:

```
var testObject = 
{
    testDiv: $("#testDiv"),
    testDivProperty: this.testDiv    
};
```

Why is it when I access `testObject.testDiv` I get a reference to a jQuery object, i.e.,

```
[<div id=​"testDiv">​…​</div>​]
```

but when I access `testObject.testDivProperty` I get a reference to the actual element, i.e.,

```
<div id=​"testDiv">​…​</div>​
```

and hence am not able to perform jQuery operations on `testObject.testDivProperty`?

Comment: You *can* perform jQuery operations on it, but it means wrapping it again - `$(testObject.testDivProperty);`.  I'm just commenting though.  I'm as curious about this as you are :)

Comment: Personally on Chrome I get `undefined` when querying `testObject.testDivProperty` (tested using `body` instead of `#testDiv`).

Comment: I just tested in Chrome, using the above code, and got the same result as the OP.

Comment: This is the expected result, but I'm not really sure why exactly the jQuery element is unwrapped? -> http://jsfiddle.net/CQw5v/

Comment: I would have expected `this.testDiv` to be `undefined`, but for some reason `window.testDiv` exists...(I get the [same result](http://jsfiddle.net/zmGPd/) as OP and Archer running in Chrome Canary)

Comment: @Archer That's incredibly odd. [Here's what happens for me](http://screencast.com/t/IcDbNk6XArQ).

Comment: When trying to assign inside a function, works ok: http://jsfiddle.net/CQw5v/1/ but outside, I get same as those before me.

Comment: `this` is the window object, and this.testDiv references the native DOM element as it's attached to the window in some browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) combined with [Should the id of elements be made global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/should-the-id-of-elements-be-made-global-variables-and)

Comment: Also note that the element ID will only be attached to the window if no such property already exists. This means that if you start using this crappy method of accessing elements, and you create a DIV with the ID `history`, `location`, or anything else that already exists in the window object, you obviously can't access those elements with `window.location`, as that's already taken, causing even more confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to refer to the object you're defining as `this` during object instantiation doesn't work like you're expecting it to.

`this` in your example actually refers to the `window` object. Some browsers (e.g., Chrome and IE) will attach named DOM nodes to the `document` and/or `window` objects, which is why `this.testDiv` refers to the element with `id="testDiv"`. It just so happens the property name you're trying to access has the same value as the element ID.

To demonstrate what's really going on, try this:

```
<div id="test"></div>

var myObj = {
    prop1: $('#test'),
    prop2: this.prop1
};
```

`this.prop1` in the context of `myObj` should be `undefined`, but `window.test` may (depending on the browser) refer to the DOM node `<div id="test"></div>`.

Given your example, you could do your assignment as follows:

```
var myObj = { prop1: $('#test') };
myObj.prop2 = myObj.prop1;
```

or

```
var test = $('#test');
var myObj = {
    prop1: test,
    prop2: test
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work. `this` is `window` in this context.

```
var testObject = 
{
    testDiv: $("#testDiv"),
    testDivProperty: this.testDiv // window.testDiv

}
```

Comment: But why does `testDiv` exist as a property of `window`, and why does it reference the correct DOM node? Is this documented behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't. `this.testDiv` is undefined. You are setting `testDiv` elsewhere, possibly accidentally leaking it as a global. If, anywhere else in your code, you're doing `testDiv = ...` without first scoping it with `var testDiv`, you're creating a `testDiv` property on `window`.

Comment: In some browsers elements are attached to the window by name or ID, that's why window.testDiv works, it's the ID of the element.

Comment: @meagar It's not `undefined` though (at least not in Chrome). That's what's surprising for me.

Comment: @adeneo Ah, of course. Your browser *may* be biting you that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: @meager - try it in the console on this page.  Just append the div to `body` and then create the variable.  You'll see it work just as described.

Comment: @Archer - depending on the browser. IE used this crap for years, and it works in Chrome as well, but it's not really standarized, so one shouldn't rely on it, but it's the reason this strange example is working in some browsers.

Comment: @Archer Yes, this has nothing to do with the code in qustion though. As adeneo points out, Chrome is adding the div to the window by its ID. The problem only appears because the variable name and div ID happen to be the same.

Comment: @adeneo Actually, it's completely standard behaviour, and browsers are *supposed* to do it.

Comment: It's in the drafts, and will probably be standarized, but I don't think Firefox supports this at all, and it's a really bad practice to clutter the window object with all the values of the id and/or name attribute "of any HTML element in the active document with a non-empty attribute".

Comment: @meagar Yes, I know - see my answer below ;)

Comment: @adeneo Plus there's the obvious issue that *will* occur when people call elements by the same name as existing window properties.  Personally I think it sucks and has trouble written all over it.

Comment: @adeneo Firefox does support it, so do all browsers which correctly and fully implement HTML5.

Comment: window.testDiv depends on browser

Comment: @Salim So does literally everything. I think what you're implying is that `window.testDiv` is *non-standard*, but that isn't the case. This is completely standard HTML5, and modern Webkit, Firefox and IE all support it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#DOM_differences

Comment: @meagar - as noted earlier, it's in the drafts for HTML 5.1, so how it can be completely standard HTML5 is beyond me? You are however right in that the newer versions of Firefox also supports this.

Comment: @adeneo It's in HTML5, regardless 5.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Those are recommendations for the spec, posted a few months ago ?

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around I found the answer.  At the time that you create the 2nd property, `this` refers to `window`, where you have a div with the id of `testDiv`.

So you're actually doing this...

```
var testObject = 
{
    testDiv: $("#testDiv"),
    testDivProperty: window.testDiv    
}
```

I personally wasn't aware that you could do this, but `window.testDiv` returns the DOM element with the ID `testDiv`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, **this** refers to the global window object.

The reason **this.testDiv** refers to the DOM element is because of a standard behavior in web browsers to add a global references to every DOM element with an id. The references are added as the elements are parsed, so your script code must be located below the element to reference.

Whether to rely on these references or not is another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in first case getting the jQuery object is obvious and should be understood (as you used '`$`'). In the second case, you get reference to a simple `DOM` node(object) because of these reasons-

**- You didn't use jQuery anywhere in it, so don't expect it to be a
   jQuery object.**

**- You accessed `this.testDiv` meaning that -
give me the    property named
   "testDiv" of the current node(which is being    accessed)
Now if you have written this code in the `<body>` tag then `this`    should point to the node/object(in DOM) of `body` element. I am not    sure on this part but, somehow your '`testDiv`' object was registered    as a property in the body object(maybe because you used an "id"    attribute for this element, thus making it unique). Thus, when you tried getting the object using `this.testDiv` you got the exact object for the `<div>` element in the DOM. And, javascript by default gives you a simple reference to the DOM/javascript object(not the jQuery object).**

Apart from this, jQuery objects can be thought of as a coating over the normal javascript/DOM objects. It was not part of the question but still if you want to access as a jQuery object then,

To convert javascript object `Obj` to jQuery object, do this
 `Obj=$(Obj);`

The new `Obj` will be a jQuery object.

Comment: No. `this` would not point to the `<body>` element when the script is included there. What made you think that?

Answer (score 0):

```
let object = $('#someId') -- jQueryObject

accesing any custom object field

object[0].anyProp = 'anyValue'

console.log(object) -- jQuery object
console.log(object[0]) -- Raw JS object
console.log(object[0].anyProp) -- Raw JS object prop
```