# createElement does not work

Tags: javascript

what's wrong with my code..? the div with a anchor tag with a img does not popup in the section area when i call this function

```
function addLink(){

  if(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') >= 1){
    localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', Number(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks')) + 1);
  }
  else{
    localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', '1');
  }

  var howManyLinks = localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks');

  var myNewLink = document.getElementById("link");
    localStorage.setItem('link'+howManyLinks, myNewLink.value);

  var myNewIcon = document.getElementById("icon");
    localStorage.setItem('icon'+howManyLinks, myNewIcon.value);

/* below here is where i have trubble */

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  var a = document.createElement('a');

  img.setAttribute('src','icon'+howManyLinks);
  a.setAttribute('href','link'+howManyLinks);

  section.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(a);
  a.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: nothing is happening when i call the function

Comment: What is `section`, and where is it defined/assigned?

Comment: its a normal element in my html

Comment: And you're using it as a variable, unless you assign a particular `section` element to the variable named `section` all you have is an undefined variable error. Which should be evident in your browser's console.

Comment: @Satpal where should i put that ?

Comment: what is section in your code..? where it is defined..

Comment: @Satpal When i did as you said something a "broken" img icon poped up for a second

Comment: i can suggest you to just the line `section.appendChild(div)` to `document.getElementById("yoursectionId").appendChild(div);`

Comment: @DavidThomas If the markup includes an `id="section"`, [it should exist as a global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/should-the-id-of-elements-be-made-global-variables-and).

Comment: @Jon: but that's a non-standard behaviour introduced by, if I recall correctly, IE (in its early days) and maintained for legacy reasons, with other browsers allowing it also. It is, though, poor practice to rely upon it, however. And there's no reason to believe that an element with that `id` *is* present in the HTML; especially since the function clearly/reportedly *doesn't work*.

Comment: @user2971409 Are you getting any errors when trying to use `addLink()`? If so, can you include there messages? Also, would you be able to include a snippet of the markup related to `addLink()`? Perhaps with a small example in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah, I believe it started with IE. But, has actually been [drafted by the WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-window-nameditem) as a required feature. And, of course, such an element may not be in the document. Thus, the "*if*" in my comment. :) Was just trying to say that it's not guaranteed to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To concentrate on your trouble part: This works with Firefox 25.0 / Linux:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section">
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var section = document.getElementById("section");

        img.setAttribute('src', 'dummyImg2.jpg');
        a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.example.com');

        section.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(a);
        a.appendChild(img);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```