# Are html5 element ids automatically mapped as object id in javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, html

I often see in many javascript samples here, getting the object name by:

```
 var id = document.getElementById("MyId");
 id.play();  //MyId above is that of an <audio> element
```

In my javascript code, on chromebook and android, I can directly use the element id as object name  without the first line above.  Are ids now automatically mapped into the javascript namespace?  For example, in the html I have,

```
 <audio id="MyId" controls>
```

Then in the javascript, I can use the code below successfully:

```
 MyId.play();
```

Could somebody please explain why I do not need to execute the getElementById() first?

Thank

Comment: This was a shortcut implemented by some browsers that I do not think is a standard behavior universally implemented.  Plus, any library or piece of your own code that implements a global variable with the same name as one of these id values will replace the id variable.  It was a bad idea to implement it that way and IMO it's a bad idea to code to it.

Comment: and [Should the id of elements be made global variables? And](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6381425/218196)

Comment: _"Are ids now automatically mapped into the javascript namespace?"_ - This isn't a new feature with html5 (as sort of implied by your "now"), but as the other comments indicate it won't work in all browsers.

Comment: I think this auto name mapping does take place for all the elements.  Perhaps only for the newer elements?  For things like <div> one may have to use getElementById() in js; I have not verified this, but I do see in my code a lot of the above method usage.