# Adding dynamically text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, text, dynamically-generated

Javascript:

```
function changeIt()
{
    var i = 1;
    var j = 1;
    my_div.innerHTML = "<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext' + i  value='pleaseEnter malzeme' >   <input type='text' name='mytet2'+j value='please quantity'> "
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Ingredients" onClick="changeIt()" />
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

I have these code piece to add textbox dynamically in my HTML file. Problem is that I cannot reach text.

```
System.out.print(request.getParameter("mytext1")); //doesnt work to reach mytext1 value.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to have a function `request.getParameter` nor do you have `out.print`. Have you tried looking in your console? (hit F12) you'll see a bunch of errors in there.

Comment: Is this a Java question or a JavaScript question? Either way, you aren't showing us enough code.

Comment: @MikeC That is Java code. They are showing the back-end, which has no F12.

Comment: out.print(request.getParameter("mytext1")) returns null value, but when i change to out.print(request.getParameter("mytext")) returns not null value. I think problem is on concatenation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first to get a reference of an element in JavaScript you need to call `document.getElementById("my_div")`. There is no such thing as automatic global scope population with IDs in JS.

Then your HTML string contains variables which are written as part of the string. Concatenation in JS works with the plus sign (+). So your string should be:

```
"<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext" + i + "' value='pleaseEnter malzeme'><input type='text' name='mytet2" + j + "' value='please quantity'>"
```

Everything assembled together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIt() {
    var i = 1;
    var j = 1;
    document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = "<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext" + i + "' value='pleaseEnter malzeme'><input type='text' name='mytet2" + j + "' value='please quantity'>"
}
</script>

<input type="button"  value="Add Ingredients" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Regarding the print I have no idea what you're actually trying there...

Comment: really thanks for this answer. Nearly 5-6 hours, i tried to solve this problem.

Comment: **There is no such thing as automatic global scope population with IDs in JS.** See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info. However I think JS starters are better off not knowing something like this exists. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your innerHTML to this:

```
my_div.innerHTML ="<br><br><input type='text' name='mytext" + i + "' value='pleaseEnter malzeme' >   <input type='text' name='mytet2" +j + "' value='please quantity'> "
```