# Why variable name is set by default in browser?

Tags: javascript

I need help understanding something that I'm learning.  Some lines of my code set a variable, *name*, which holds a name for a user and is set when an element is clicked.

The problem I've discovered is even without clicking the element, a user may still access it in the console.

I thought something was wrong with my code but I found the same accessing it on another site; for instance, accessing the variable on [facebook](http://www.facebook.com) yields `"_e_0MDe"`.  Other sites yield empty strings, like `""`.

Why does this happen?
Thank you.

Comment: "_I tried accessing variable name under facebook_" What **exactly** did you do?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Could you provide code examples?

Comment: In javascript, you don't have to define your variables with `var`. as soon as you assign a value, it will be defined.

Comment: is `name` a global variable, or an attribute of a DOM element, or what exactly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: @guyfawkes If you don't use `var`, you're going to have a bad day…

Comment: `name` is a reserved word. You should use more specific variable names in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

Comment: Why are you responding to the posted answers, but not to any of the questions we asked you?

Comment: @deceze If you don't use `const`/`let`, you're going to have a bad day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is just part of the DOM API. Facebook must be setting it.

If you declare a variable in a bare script tag, its treated as part of `window`

```
<script>
  var name = 'foo';
  console.log(window.name); // "foo"
</script>
```

In order to prevent that use a function to create a new scope (or use `let`)

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var name = 'foo';
  })();
  console.log(window.name); // what ever it was before this function call
</script>
```

Comment: oh okay... please do you have a list of such?

Comment: Seems like the most plausible explanation, given that OP probably uses a global variable.

Comment: @jamesOduro a list of what?

Comment: @jamesOduro Type "window" in the console and see what properties it has.

Comment: Thank you so much...that was much understandable

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, like many scripting languages, can be very loose in variable declarations and initializations.  This allows for quick development, but also means you have to be aware of [scoping](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html).

What you may be seeing is a collision in the global scope.  By default, browsers have a global object called, `window`.  This object can be used anywhere, in any function that you declare.

When you don't initialize a variable in a block with one of the reserved words (`var`, `let`, `function`, `class`, `import`, `const`), the global scope may be used.  For instance, the following are equivalent:

- ```
  name = 'foo';
  window.name = 'foo';
  ```

To help avoid syntax mistakes, developers often include a magical phrase at the top of their code:

- ```
  "use strict";
  ```

More information can be found on John Resig's [strict mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) site.