# Uncaught TypeError when calling function from button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, typeerror

I'm making a form to record data from a group of people, and when pressing the button to add another person, the console spits out a TypeError, saying addPerson() is not a function.

HTML (body):

```
<form method="POST">
    <h3> People </h3>
    <div class="person">
        <p>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <br/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
            <br />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="dob" />
            <br/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add another person" onclick="addPerson()" id="addPerson" />
</form>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function addPerson(){
    let personForm = document.getElementsByClassName("person")[0];
    let personFormCopy = personForm.cloneNode(true);
    let buttonNode = document.getElementById("addPerson");
    document.body.insertBefore(personFormCopy, buttonNode);

    let br150 = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.insertBefore(br150, buttonNode);

    br150.style.lineHeight="150px";
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: addPerson is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your function and the button ID are the same. Ever since IE introduced this behavior, some browsers [add DOM element IDs to the `window` scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable), which is causing conflicts in your case.

This problem can be solved by changing the ID of the button to `addPersonBtn`, for example.

However, I would suggest not mixing HTML and JS. You could instead remove the `onclick` attribute in your HTML, and write your JS like so:

```js
document.getElementById('addPersonBtn').addEventListener('click', addPerson);

function addPerson(){
    console.log('It worked.');
}
```

```html
<button id="addPersonBtn">Click me</button>
```