# Javascript not being executed when called from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I'm trying to make a simple HTML file with a checkbox and a javascript that change the color of the checkbox when clicked. The problem is that the javascript file is not called, so clicking the button is useless as the javascript code is not being read. It seens very simple but I can't see what am I doing wrong:

HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="and_gate.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body style= "background-color: white;">

  <label id=in1 class="container1" onclick="in1(element1)">0
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <style>
    .container1 {
      background-color:green;
      font-size: 2vw;
    }
    </style>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Javascript code:

```
alert('clicked')
funtion in1(element1){
  element1.style="background-color:red;"
}
```

Comment: 1. You aren't setting `element1`. 2. Your `alert()` is not inside the `in1` function.

Comment: You are also not passing in an `element1` on your method call

Comment: You should move your `<script>` element to your `<head>` and add `defer` instead of having it at the end of your document.

Comment: I updated the code. I forgot about element1, and I moved the <script> to the <head> (I thought that wasn't necessary). I put the alert outside the function to check if the javascript code was read (to rule out problems with the button). The code still doesn't work for me

Comment: You should separate your CSS and JavaScript from your HTML, as a best practice. Just a comment.

Comment: Well, what are you passing as `element1`? You could also try attaching your event handler using JavaScript instead of using inline attributes (i.e., `document.getElementById("in1").addEventListener("click", function() { in1(whateverElement1Is); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an inline event handler, you can use `this` to refer to the target of the event.

You also misspelled `function`. And the alert needs to be inside the function.

```js
function in1_fun(element1) {
  alert('clicked')
  element1.style = "background-color:red;"
}
```

```css
.container1 {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<label id=in1 class="container1" onclick="in1_fun(this)">0
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

It's also not a good idea to use the same name for your function as the ID of the element. Both of these become global variables, and it's possible for the ID variable to replace the function variable.

Comment: IIRC, element `id=""` attributes become properties on the `document` object and not the `window` object; and only `window` object properties are "global" (so it would be `document.in1`, not `window.in1` (or `in1` in the root scope)) - but yes, it would still cause confusion.

Comment: No, they become `window` properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript and HTML, when you pass a JS function to the `onclick` property of an element, the function doesn't know about the element that's calling it. You need to pass it some way to find that element, like an *id* (or the outer context through `this`, which I missed, and as Barmar points out in [his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63947216/11047824)).

You can then use this ID with a function like `document.getElementById()` to find the desired element in the DOM, and do something with it, in this case change it's `style` property.

You also misspelled *function* as "funtion", which will cause it not to be processed as a function.

```js
function in1(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style = "background-color:red;"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="and_gate.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">

  <label id=in1 class="container1" onclick="in1('in1')">0
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <style>
    .container1 {
      background-color: green;
      font-size: 2vw;
    }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```