# Clear in Google Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

When I type clear in console, it gives me g id=clear and then a path. What does it mean?

I am not able to understand the value, so looking for some help :)

Screenshot of  developer tool

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a spec that the id of elements should be made global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable)

Comment: There is an element with the `id="clear"` within the document, making it a global variable. That is what you are printing there.

Comment: Also: [Do DOM tree elements with IDs become global properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-properties)

Comment: I could not find anything similar.

Comment: @Ivar could you please tell from where this id is coming and what does the path specify?

Comment: This tag is somewhere in the HTML of that page. You'll need to ask the developers how it got there. [`<path>` is just an HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path).

Comment: I dont think it is coming from any HTML. You can simply start an Incognito window and just type clear in console.

Comment: The default page that is shown when you open a new tab still has HTML. Right click on the `<g id="clear">...</g>` and then click on "Reveal in Elements panel" to show the rest of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the console, you can execute `clear()` (notice the parenthesis after), or even `console.clear()`.

Basically, as noticed above, you are likely accessing a global element from the DOM. In this case, you should be calling the `clear()` function or `console.clear()` function, rather than just entering the variable.

Comment: Yes,  I know that I have to type console.clear(). I typed only clear by mistake and wanted to know what is this  path value.