JS variable from html undefined
I wrote this code 2-3 years ago for a class and it worked perfectly. I know this as I got a perfect score on the assignment it was for. But recently I went back to the program and found that it no longer works. The console says that the variable "letterNumber" is undefined, but two similar variables, "numberNumber" and "speacialNumber" are fine so I'm lost. I am incredibly rusty in Javascript as I havent touched it since this assignment so I was wondering if anyone would be willing to help me find the issue. The code is below
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>replit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <center>

    <h1>Password Generator</h1>

      <p>Select your desired settings below and the password will automatically generate!</p>


      <div class="subHead"><p>Letter Case Settings:</p></div>

      <div id="radioMixDiv">
          <input id="radioMix" type="radio" name="capCheck" onchange="setLength('mix')"   checked>
            <label for="">Uppercase and Lowercase</label>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <input id="radioUpper" type="radio" name="capCheck" onchange="setLength('caps')">
            <label for="">Uppercase Only</label>
      </div>
      <div id="radioLowerDiv">
        <input id="radioLower" type="radio" name="capCheck" onchange="setLength('lows')">
            <label for="">Lowercase Only</label>
      </div>

      <div class="subHead"><p>Character Number Settings:</p></div>

      <div id="letterNumberDiv">
        <label for="letterNumber">Number of Letters:</label>
        <select name="letterNumber" id="letterNumber" onchange="setLength()"></select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="numberNumber">Number of Numbers:</label>
        <select name="numberNumber" id="numberNumber" onchange="setLength()"></select>
      </div>
      <div id="speacialNumberDiv">
        <label for="speacialNumber">Number of Special Characters:</label>
        <select name="speacialNumber" id="speacialNumber" onchange="setLength()"></select>
      </div>
     
     
      <div>
        <button id="btnRenderPassword" onclick="setLength()">New Password</button>
        <button id="btnCopy" onclick="copyPassword()">Copy</button>
      </div>


      <div id="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="outPassword"></input></div>


        <script src="data.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </center>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </body>
</html>

data.js
var letters = [
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
];

var speacialChars = [
  "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "?", ".", "_", "-"
];

script.js
//App: Password Generator

//Date: 2/25/22


//DOCUMENT OBJECTS
var passLengthDropdown = document.getElementById("passLength");
var radioMix = document.getElementById("radioMix");
var radioLetter = document.getElementById("radioLetter");
var radioNumber = document.getElementById("radioNumber");
var outPassword = document.getElementById("outPassword");

//VARIABLES
var password = [];
var passLength = "";
var capsSetting = "mix";

//INIT
init();


//FUNCTIONS
//Start program by running the setLength and fillDropdowns functions
function init() {
  fillDropdowns();
  setLength();
}


//Cycle through the three dropdowns (letters, numbers, and specials), and fill them with numbers up to 50.
function fillDropdowns() {
  for (i = 0; i < 51; i++)
  {
    var lengthChild = document.createElement("option");
        lengthChild.innerHTML = i;  
        letterNumber.appendChild(lengthChild);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 51; i++)
  {
    var lengthChild = document.createElement("option");
        lengthChild.innerHTML = i;  
        numberNumber.appendChild(lengthChild);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 51; i++)
  {
    var lengthChild = document.createElement("option");
        lengthChild.innerHTML = i;  
        speacialNumber.appendChild(lengthChild);
  }   
}


//Make sure there are multiple letters when mix is checked, clear current password, and start the function to generate a new one
function setLength(radioState) {
  if (document.getElementById("radioMix").checked && letterNumber.value == 1) {
    letterNumber.value = 2;
  }
  outPassword.value = "";

  //Run "createletters" with the argument the user has selected
  if (document.getElementById("radioMix").checked) {
    createLetters("mix");
  } else if (document.getElementById("radioLower").checked) {
    createLetters("lows");
  } else {
    createLetters("caps");
  }
}


//The start of the main portion of the program. It generates a list of random letters in the number of the user's input. It then checks to see what the desired case of the letters is and racts by either leaving the letters untouched, randomly changing some to lowercase, or changing all to lowercase. If a mix of capitilization is chosen the function also checks to make sure there is at least one capital and one lowercase letter, and if there is not it randomly changes one letter's capitilization to accordingly.
function createLetters(radioState) {
var charList = [];

  if ((parseInt(letterNumber.value) > 0)) {
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(letterNumber.value); i++) {
      charList.push(letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)]);
    }

  var tempLetters = "";

  if (radioState == "mix") {
    //generate list of letters. Generate random number, and if 1 leave it if 2 lowercase it. Make sure there is at least 1 upper and 1 lower.
    var lowNumb = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
      var randomNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
      if (randomNumb == 1) {
        var givenLetter = charList[i];
        givenLetter = givenLetter.toLowerCase();
        charList.splice(i, 1, givenLetter);
        lowNumb += 1;
      }
    }

    //If there are no lowercase letters replace one capital letter with a lowercase one
    if (lowNumb == 0) {
      var tempNumb = (parseInt(charList.length) - 1);
      var temp = charList[tempNumb];
      temp = temp.toLowerCase(); 
      charList.splice(tempNumb);
      charList.push(temp);
    }

    //If there are no capital letters change one letter to be captal
    if (lowNumb == charList.length) {
      var tempNumb = (parseInt(charList.length) - 1);
      var temp = charList[tempNumb];
      temp = temp.toUpperCase(); 
      charList.splice(tempNumb);
      charList.push(temp);
    }
    
  //If lowercase only is selected assign all letters to lowercase
  } else if (radioState == "lows") {
    for (i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
      tempLetters += charList[i];
    }
    tempLetters = tempLetters.toLowerCase();
    console.log(tempLetters + " (lowercase)");
    charList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < tempLetters.length; i++) {
      charList.push(tempLetters[i]);
    }
  }
  }

createNumbers(charList);
}


//The function adds a random sequence of numbers to charList in the number that is chosen by the user.
function createNumbers(charList) {
  if ((parseInt(numberNumber.value) > 0)) {
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(numberNumber.value); i++) {
      charList.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    }
  }

createSpecial(charList);
}


//The function adds a number (selected by the user) of random "special characters" from the speacialChars array to the charList function.
function createSpecial(charList) {
  if ((parseInt(speacialNumber.value) > 0)) {
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(speacialNumber.value); i++) {
      charList.push(speacialChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * speacialChars.length)]);
    }
  }
  
randomizePassword(charList);
}


//Loop through the list of characters for the password (charList), and randomly re-order it, then run cleanPassword()
function randomizePassword(charList) {
  for (i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tempStore = charList[i];
    charList[i] = charList[j];
    charList[j] = tempStore;
  }
  console.log(charList);
  cleanPasword(charList);
}


//Copy each value from the array to a new string and display it on the screen.
function cleanPasword(charList) {
  var drawnPass = "";
  for (i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
    console.log(charList[i]);
    drawnPass += charList[i];
  }
  outPassword.value = drawnPass;
}


//On "Copy" button click select the password text and copy it to the clipboard
function copyPassword() {
  outPassword.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(outPassword.value);
}


I do not see letterNumber being defined anywhere, do you?

You're relying on the automatic id-to-variable browser feature which is rarely a good idea. Couldn't say why it's not working for that one though

You need to declare the variables accordingly, see https://jsfiddle.net/9trd70hv/ for an example of what you are missing.   Namely, letterNumber not being declared.

@chiliNUT Yes, I see it in the HTML code: <div id="letterNumberDiv">. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

@Vahe No, it should also work with HTML IDs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable

Oh thanks @Phil I didn't know about that feature
